# In Vue.js, is this a wrong writing for v-on?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

i want to make two button to input number.

but when the left one goes to 10, it looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YguWU.jpg)

i want it to be 2 on the left while 0 on the right side.

so i changed my code:

```
<div id="counter-event-example">
<p>{{ total }}</p>
<button-counter v-on:increment="incrementTotal2"></button-counter>
<button-counter v-on:increment2="incrementTotal"></button-counter>
</div>
Vue.component('button-counter', {
    template: '<button v-on:click="increment">{{ counter }}</button><button v-on:click="increment2">{{ counter }}</button>',
    data: function () {
        return {
            counter: 0
        }
    },
    methods: {
        increment: function () {
            this.counter += 1
            this.$emit('increment')
        },
        increment2:function () {
            if(this.counter === 10){
                this.counter = 0;
                this.increment();
            }
            this.$emit('increment2')
        }
    },
})
new Vue({
    el: '#counter-event-example',
    data: {
        total: 0
    },
    methods: {
        incrementTotal: function () {
            this.total += 1
        },
        incrementTotal2: function () {
            this.total  = this.total +10
        }

    }
})
```

but it did'nt work..[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHhKk.jpg)

i click the right button, the total number wont change.

Comment: Define "Didn't work"

Comment: i click the right one, the total number wont change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You render 2 components each of them should render 2 buttons. Sounds about right? If you check Element Inspector you will see that rendered only 2 buttons. 2 + 2 === 2 - something is fishy...

Dev version of Vue telling you in console "Error compiling template... Component template should contain exactly one root element".

So each button-counter render **first** button => writing you warning => and ignoring second button.

```
<div id="counter-event-example">
  <p>{{ total }}</p>
  <button-counter-1 @increment="incrementTotal"></button-counter-1>
  <button-counter-2 @increment="incrementTotal"></button-counter-2>
</div>
```

---

```
Vue.component('button-counter-1', {
    template: '<button @click="increment1">{{ counter }}</button>',
    data: function() {
        return { counter: 0 }
    },
    methods: {
        increment1: function () {
            this.counter++;
            this.$emit('increment', 10);
        }
    }
});
Vue.component('button-counter-2', {
    template: '<button @click="increment2">{{ counter }}</button>',
    data: function() {
        return { counter: 0 }
    },
    methods: {
        increment2: function () {
            this.counter++;
            this.$emit('increment', 1);
        }
    }
})
new Vue({
    el: '#counter-event-example',
    data: {
        total: 0
    },
    methods: {
        incrementTotal: function (n) {
            this.total += n;
        },
    }
})
```

Comment: What was the problem?

Comment: I believe template should contain **exactly** 1 root Element. At least dev version of Vue screaming this at you  in console...

Comment: You're right. That gets me a lot. You should note it in your answer.